# How to upload (import) with overwrite azure database using sqlpackage.exe

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqlpackage

It should be a simple thing to do, I want to upload/import my database with overwrite option, but I can't find it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)

I have to delete it manually and upload with Import.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

Generate backup:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe"
   /a:Export /ssn:"windowsusername\sqlexpress" /sdn:yourdbname /tf:yourdbname.bacpac
```

Drop existing database using `sqlcmd`:

```
sqlcmd -U dbusernameonazure@azureservename.database.windows.net
   -P yourpassword -S azureservename.database.windows.net -Q "drop DATABASE yourdbname"
```

Import database:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe"
   /a:Import /SourceFile:yourdbname.bacpac
   /tsn:azureservename.database.windows.net,1433
   /tdn:yourdbname /tu:dbusernameonazure /tp:yopurpassword
```